# Emerald Green Arborvitae - Lost their cone shape

Tags: pruning, trimming

Just moved into a new home, and although the Arborvitae's were pruned, they lost their "cone" shape and now look more like Grimace from McDonalds. Each are about 6 foot high.

Is there a progressive method to get them back to being the cone? Really appreciate the insight.

[image]

[image]

Comment: My experience with Emeralds (I own seven of them, as a hedge), is that they lose their shape; in my area, that's mostly due to a heavy snow load, which is why I amuse my neighbors by shoveling my trees (actually, gently knocking the snow off of them with a broom, but that's how a neighbor described it). If this is done within a day or two of the snowfall, then the arbs will spring back into shape. You can try tying the wayward stem to a taller upright stem with twine; I've had some success with that.

Comment: @Jurp Thanks. Its not that they dont have a shape, they have just been pruned more bulbous than the Christmas tree cone I would like to see. Wondering if I can aggressively trim them back to that shape or if thats a bad idea

Comment: Pictures please?

Comment: Photos would help us all with giving you the correct advice, but be careful when pruning most evergreens (the exception is yews; they'll regrow from "dead" wood). You cannot aggressively prune an arb, because once you remove all of the greenery what's left behind will either not sprout at all or will grow very, very, slowly. Note that Emeralds will not naturally grow cone-shaped, although I suppose you could try to get them cone-shaped by shortening their height.. Like all arbs, they're columnar, and unlike many arb cultivars Emeralds are EXTREMELY columnar.

Comment: Thanks .. added some pics

@Jurp

Comment: The agressiveness of your prune needs to be compatible wih the depth of live foliage where you'll take the most off. That will probably mean several rounds of pruning the upper half only - imagine that you with the hedge trimmer are the pencil sharpener (since you want a cone) and you don't want to see no green foliage in the area you are cutting away the most from. Might take a couple of years.

Comment: It looks like at least two of those have been topped... To reshape them, you'll have to follow @Ecnerwal's advice and make many cuts over a long period. Personally, I'd use a manual shear rather than a power hedge clipper - you'll have more control and it'll be less easy to make an "oops!" cut.